# Blackberry User Agent

Tags: browser, blackberry, user-agent

I'm hitting a mobile site from a new Blackberry and the user agent is:

mozilla/5.0 (windows, u; windows nt)....

Anyone else seen this?

On older phones it was blackberry8130...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your browsers settings? You can configure the BB browser to emulate Firefox or IE.

Comment: Looks like blackberry by default has Firefox emulation selected.